# Make an element with full Height (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I searched a lot and found lots of ways to doing this. but each of them some **cons** that i couldn't ignore.

If you visited [w3school](http://w3schools.com/css/) website, I'm sure you'd notice the **sidebar** navigator in the left. I like that and wanted to create something like it.

Though at the first glance it's pretty simple, But it's not!!

With a beautiful trick i did something like this:

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
      font-size: 35px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: block;
  }
  .container {
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #eee;
  }
  .row {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #555;
      left: 25%;
  }
  .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: block;
  }
  header, footer {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 30px;
      margin: 0;
  }

  header h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  nav {
      position: relative;
      /*position: fixed;*/
      overflow-y: scroll;
      top: 0;
      right: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      /*background-color: #eee;*/
  }
  ul {
      /*overflow: scroll;*/
  }
  section{
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 80px;
      right: 25%;
  }
  .col-3 {width: 25%;float: left;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;float: left;}
```

```html
<header><h1>HELL!<h1></header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <nav class="col-3">
    <ul>
     <li>first</li>
     <li>second</li>
     <li>third</li>
     
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <section class="col-9">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis. Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl. Aliquam ullamcorper interdum est nec tincidunt.
   </p></section>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer><h3>HELL!<h3></footer>
```

But as you can see, **scrollbar** of the navigation list still matches the size of content of it, and that's the problem with this method.

**Faux Column** method is cool, but i don't like use *images* in my design.

As i said i saw a few other methods too, but all had *problems*.

*(and of course i don't want to use **JavaScript** or anything. just **CSS**)*

So if you have an **special method** or something that i could use *(something like **w3school**)* Please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is 2 structures where both are dynamic and fill the viewport height, the first use `flex`,

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  flex: 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
}
footer {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <section>Section</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

and the second use `display: table`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
header div {
  height: 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
main {
  height: 100%;
}
aside {
  width: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
}
footer div {
  height: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    Header
  </div>
</header>
<main class="row">
  <aside class="cell">Aside</aside>
  <section class="cell">Section</section>
</main>
<footer class="row">
    <div class="cell">
  Footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. But I'm not comfortable with flex. though i couldn't work with it like you do! If you have an opinion on the layout that i posted, i'll be greatfull. Thanks again.

Comment: @ElSHEN Updated with a 2:nd version. To avoid the scroll you refer to, both my samples do that, where both header and footer is dynamic without create the scroll, unless content fills the page.

Comment: actually i've changed your older answer and it worked great with scroll too! as i said before, it was really great code. but i want something that matches my **layout**. *(of course if i didn't find it, i'll use your code)*. about your 2nd version, i read somewhere that table- has a problem with **IE**. so the older one was better! Thanks again Man!

Comment: @ElSHEN My first _old_ code is still there, the second with table does not have any issues with IE, it works prefect down to IE8, ... and my code, both samples, have exactly the layout yours have, you just need to change the paddings, height etc. and add your inner elements.

Comment: Thanks man. yeah, actually at first i didn't saw it! That's my bad. Maybe i read wrong or the article has problem about table style, but i'll search again. and When i said my layout, i meant with columns; not with Flexbox or table or anything else! but still, you code works great.