# Container with height:100% is larger than the whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill the content container to 100% of the height while having a 30px header. But currently, the content container is larger than 100% which results in a scrollbar.

**Code**

```css
html {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
body {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
#header {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  padding-top:30px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/48SJjl9dB7S7IiC8JLcP?p=preview

What's the correct way to accomplish this? If it's possible I would even prefer to have the header positioned "relatively" and not absolute. But probably that's not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an element with full Height (HTML/CSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160775/make-an-element-with-full-height-html-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try and make these changes:

```
#container{
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

You can remove the `position` properties on both elements, as `static` will work just fine here.

[**Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PERiPtFkU1ywgs17Gex3?p=preview)

You are setting your `content` element to `height: 100%` which means it will take up the full height available from the parent element (`body` in this case). But `header` is also a child of `body` and you're giving it a height of `30px`. 100% + 30px would exceed the full height available, and thus your scroll-bar. Adding `padding-top` as well, only increases this excess height.

**Full code**

```css
html{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}

body{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}

#header{
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#container{
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="container"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have  padding-top:30px; on your container, which stretches it further. Try adding box-sizing: border-box; so your padding won't stretch your container, but will rather resize inner side.

Comment: You got downvoted for this answer, and I don't know enough to know if there was a reason. But you were the only one mentioning that solution, which was, in my case, the only solution that worked. I owe you one.

Comment: Glad to hear that.
I am not sure why it was dovnwoted, but here is the difference between this solution and others: final result will look pretty much the same in this case. "border-box" will make it so that whatever value you give to height/width will be it's final value no matter what the padding or margin is. Reducing height by fixed value will have the same result, but it's less flexible because you need to provide correct value and have to update it if something changes. On the other hand, "border-box" will infuence both width and height, and maybe someone doesn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue here is that the div.container not present only in the body there is also #header which height is 30px and this height calculated from the 100% height which mean that the current body height is 100% + 30px;
so the container height is also 100% + 30px;

you just have to change your container height to be

```
height: calc(100% - 30px);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tested this and works pretty fine:

```
    #container{  
      display:block;
      height:100%;  
      background-color: #aaaaaa;
    }
```

Comment: This will hide content beneath the header

Comment: Ah...you are completely right. Tested it without any text neither in header nor in container.